# See if user completed an order in the last 10 seconds (woocommerce)?

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Basically I can't get a redirect to work for a number of reasons the way I'd like to so I'm wanting to add a function that will run on the /my-account/ page to see if the current user ordered product A or B in the last 10 seconds (would have completed status, using autocomplete order plugin) and if so redirect them to a custom thank you page specified in the function.

I'm finding alot of functions to pull recent orders, but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction. How in 3.0 do I get the timestamp and product id of the users most recent order? Is there a hook to tie this to the /my-account/ page or will I need to hack a javascript/php work around?

Answer (score 0):

How about to run the code directly after the purchase?
You check which product it was (and more checks if you need) and then redirect to the custom thankyou page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_code' );
function my_custom_code( $order_id ) {

    // Lets grab the order
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // do stuff

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

- added a custom column to the 'Orders' table of the 'My Account' page
  that included order ID (used filter to add the column - SKU - and
  then updated the logic in the orders.php page to add the product ID
  to the SKU column.

  `function new_orders_columns( $columns = array() ) {
      $columns['product-name'] = __( 'SKU', 'Text Domain' );
      return $columns;
  }
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'new_orders_columns' );`
- added a jQuery script (echoed with php via shortcode added to the 'My
  Account' page) that would pull the current date, the datetime
  attribute from the date column and the product ID text from the SKU
  column from the first row - ie most recent order
- used Javascript to find the difference between the current time and
  the order time and convert that number to seconds
- added a conditional redirect based on the value of that time
  difference being less than 10 (seconds) and that product id was a
  specific id

  `function mycustomorder_redirect() {
     if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $time_now = date( 'c' );
        echo '<script>jQuery("document").ready(function() { 
                //
                //Get most recent order datetime
                var lastorder_td = jQuery("td.woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-date:eq(0) time").attr("datetime"); 
                //
                //Get most recent order product id
                var product_check = jQuery("td.woocommerce-orders-table__cell-product-name:eq(0)").text(); 
                //
                //Remove whitespace
                product_check = product_check.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,"");
                //
                //Get current datetime
                var current_wrap = "' . $time_now . '";
                //
                //Remove +00:00 or -00:00
                lastorder_td = lastorder_td.substring(0, lastorder_td.length - 6); 
                current_wrap = current_wrap.substring(0, current_wrap.length - 6);
                //
                //Convert to javascript date 
                var column_a = new Date(current_wrap); 
                var column_b = new Date(lastorder_td); 
                //
                //Find time difference
                var dif = column_a - column_b; 
                //
                //Convert to seconds
                var seconds_toredirect = dif / 1000; 
                //
                //Add redirect
                if (seconds_toredirect < 10 && (product_check == 1 || product_check == 2)) { 
                  window.location.replace("https://exampleurl.com/page/"); 
                } 
              });
              </script>';
     }
  }
  add_shortcode( 'order-custom', 'mycustomorder_redirect' );`